# InterfaceError(0, '') when sending concurrent requests

Tags: python, flask, pymysql

I'm building a simple app using Flask and PyMySQL to be load-tested using JMeter for academic purposes. It already receives requests and sending out responses. But when I send multiple requests, it spews out the error below after a few requests (sometimes as few as one request).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/BossFight/python/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/username/BossFight/python/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/username/BossFight/python/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/username/BossFight/python/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/home/username/BossFight/python/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/username/BossFight/python/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/username/BossFight/python/helloflask.py", line 82, in get_driver
    if (authentication_success(token)):
  File "/home/username/BossFight/python/helloflask.py", line 21, in authentication_success
    cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) AS matches FROM users WHERE id=%s", (id))
  File "/home/username/BossFight/python/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 170, in execute
    result = self._query(query)
  File "/home/username/BossFight/python/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 328, in _query
    conn.query(q)
  File "/home/username/BossFight/python/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 515, in query
    self._execute_command(COMMAND.COM_QUERY, sql)
  File "/home/username/BossFight/python/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 745, in _execute_command
    raise err.InterfaceError("(0, '')")
pymysql.err.InterfaceError: (0, '')
```

After that, it doesn't respond with anything but HTTP 500 anymore and has to be restarted.

Here's the relevant parts of the source:

```
from flask import Flask,jsonify,request
import pymysql.cursors
import bcrypt
import jwt
from pprint import pprint

app = Flask(__name__)
connection = pymysql.connect(
host='localhost',
db='omnibus',
user='starleaf1',
password='alleluia',
cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
)

secret = 'keyboard cat'

def authentication_success(token):
    id=jwt.decode(token, secret, algorithms=['HS256'])["id"]
    cursor=connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) AS matches FROM users WHERE id=%s", (id))
    return (cursor.fetchone()['matches'] == 1)

# Other routes goes here....

@app.route('/api/driver/<string:driver_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_driver(driver_id):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    token=request.headers['Authorization'][7:]
    if (authentication_success(token)):
        cursor.execute(query_get_driver_by_id, (driver_id))
        driver=cursor.fetchone()
        if (not(driver is None)):
            return jsonify(message="ok",driver=driver)
        else:
            return jsonify(message="not found"),404
    else:
        return jsonify(message="authentication required"),401
```

Please keep in mind that I'm a beginner at Python. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your code does not contain one of the lines from the traceback.

Comment: @KlausD. Fixed it.

Comment: That was the wrong one.

Comment: @KlausD. Whoops. I see it now. I think I fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is likely that you have a global connection. In a web application, each request should have its own db connection. So your `get_driver` function should create a connection and close that connection when it is finished (in a finally clause).

So something like:

```
def create_connection():
    return pymysql.connect(
        host='localhost',
        db='omnibus',
        user='starleaf1',
        password='alleluia',
        cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor
    )

@app.route('/api/driver/<string:driver_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_driver(driver_id):
    connection = create_connection()
    try:
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        token=request.headers['Authorization'][7:]
        if (authentication_success(token)):
            cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) AS matches FROM users WHERE id=%s", (driver_id))
            driver=cursor.fetchone()
            if (not(driver is None)):
                return jsonify(message="ok",driver=driver)
            else:
                return jsonify(message="not found"),404
        else:
            return jsonify(message="authentication required"),401
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

Comment: I ended up implementing something a bit different. Most notably, calling `connection.close()` right after `driver=cursor.fetchone()`